# Received Access-Reject Id 208 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:33736

Tags: freeradius, radius

I tried to configure freeradius on centos Stream8, after the radius server is running ,I ran the radtest command to test the user, but I am getting "Received Access-Reject Id 208 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:33736"

see below steps for radius server configuration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG3SX.png)

radtest command should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

If you ran those instructions exactly as given, then you created a user in the database with username `user` and password `secret`, but then ran radtest with username `testuser` and password `password@1`. These don't match, so authentication will be rejected.

But if it's not that, there is no way near enough information in your question to answer this. You need to run FreeRADIUS in debug mode (`radiusd -X`) and read the output. You should see the packet arrive and pass through the server, at which point the place where the failure occurs will be visible.

Don't try and debug the server with no debug output; you will waste a lot of time just guessing what's going on, rather than actually having the information needed to solve the problem.